# Passing Authenticated info from WSO2 to SP App

Tags: server, wso2, identity

We are starting a project for SSO and using wso2 to do all SAML , OAuth and keep our Webapplications as service providers. 
I have been through the online documentation but need some help .

1. When user tries to Access to any resource in our webapplication i would send user to wso2 to get Authenticated in case of OAuth /openid connect , how would i form this  url ?
2. I have configured IDP and SP in WSO2 console, after authentication how does WSO2 give credentials of authenticated users to service provider , i see as per document or sample app , this should be SAML or any other sso protocols like oauth etc. documentation is not clear or any examples i can find
3. i want to redirect the user after OAuth or SAML with my own created Authn cookie , what is the provision for that .

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q. > ***When user tries to Access to any resource in our webapplication i would send user to wso2 to get Authenticated in case of OAuth /openid connect , how would i form this url ?***

**Answer :** 
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=wCmphfs69oaN3JhqO3d9FFgsNCMa&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Samplespapp/googleauth.jsp

client_id : is that if which we get on UI oof wso2 console after we finish configuring Service provider in my case i configured Inbound Authentication Configuration as OAuth open id .

redirect_uri is the url where we want to go after authentication , this should match callbackback url in View/Update application settings

**Answer 2:** I still dont see any valid reason why inbound authentication has to be sso protocol but this is how wso2 works  , to put it in laymans term i have a client to connect to using SAML and Other OAuth . i opt for a SSO vendor who takes that headache from me to implement SSO protocols but i Still have to implement atleast one SSO protocol as after SSO handshake wso2 has to communicate   userX with role as Admin to service provider app this is done again using SSO !!

ping federate makes it simple it makes an encrypted request header that had data in key value pair. may be i am not understanding but i dont like this inbound Authentication in SSO .

***Q. 3.>i want to redirect the user after OAuth or SAML with my own created Authn cookie , what is the provision for that***
documentation is poor in this area just some java classes but no end to end example , every one will point to travelocity .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can configure your application as service providers and wso2 IS as Identity provider.I guess, You can implement saml sso for your scenario and its simply documented [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/).There is another [blog](http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/04/setup-travelocitycom-sample-web-app.html) which describe the same configuration

You can download travelocity sample [code](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/tharindue/samples/travelocity/) and [war](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/tharindue/samples/travelocity/target/travelocity.com.war) file .Analysing the code you can get some idea about implementation.

By following above blogs, You can implement the complete SSO flow.

Comment: My use case is Google based Authentication , from what i have read so far . i have the following issues

1. When we add SP and give inbound auth as Oauth openid , why do this communication has to be Oauth for inbound i.e wso2 to sp application .

2. what is the url for sp app should have that initiates sso 

3. documentation and examples every thing revolves round a BIG Blackbox of travelocity that does not work with google